React Native Track Player ios Troubleshooting building 100%
I'm developing a React Native app using react-native-track-player for audio playback. The app works perfectly fine on Android, but I'm facing issues on iOS. Specifically, when building and running the app, it freezes at "Building 100%" and eventually crashes with the following error:
com.facebook.react.runtime.JavaScript (9): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Screenshot

The error occurs when i add
await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer(); 

to the code.
This is my code  :


import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import TrackPlayer,{ Capability } from 'react-native-track-player';

const AudioPlayer: React.FC = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const setupPlayer = async () => {
      await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();

      // Ajout de la piste
      const audioPath = require('../../assets/audio/teddy.mp3');
      await TrackPlayer.add({
        id: 'trackId',
        url: audioPath,
        title: 'Teddy Audio',
        artist: 'Inconnu',
        artwork: 'https://www.example.com/artwork.jpg',
      });

      // Configure les contrôles de notification
      TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
        
        capabilities: [
          Capability.Play,
          Capability.Pause,
          Capability.Stop,
        ],
        compactCapabilities: [
          Capability.Play,
          Capability.Pause,
        ],
        notificationCapabilities: [
          Capability.Play,
          Capability.Pause,
          Capability.Stop,
        ],
      });
    };

    setupPlayer();

    return () => {
      TrackPlayer.stop();
    };
  }, []);

  const playAudio = async () => {
    await TrackPlayer.play();
  };

  const pauseAudio = async () => {
    await TrackPlayer.pause();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Lire l'audio" onPress={playAudio} />
      <Button title="Pause" onPress={pauseAudio} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default AudioPlayer;



Has anyone else experienced a similar issue or found a solution?
Here is what I have tried so far:

Wrapped the setup in a try-catch block to capture any potential errors.
Verified compatibility with my React Native and react-native-track-player versions.
Ensured necessary permissions and configurations are set for Android and iOS.
add dummy.swift file


I thought RNTP didnt work with the new architecture. The image shows that bridgeless mode works. How did you do it?

thank you for your message,
I'm new to react-native, all I've done is initiate a react-native project.
made a
yarn add react-native-track-player
pod install
and tried to build the code above
tried compiling with an iphone 15 emulator and one on a real iphone 11 but the result is the same

I just started a project a week or two ago with RNTP and I couldnt get the new architecture to work. I saw that someone had a made a git repo where they got it to work so I wasnt sure if you were using that git repo or not

It wasnt giving you any issues on android?

I found the problem, there was a difference between Android and iOS
On Android, I didn't have the new architecture to activate while on iOS yes that was the problem,
I've written a comment showing the command you need to run to make it work on iOS

I figured out the issue I was facing on iOS, and it was caused by the new architecture being enabled by default with React Native. Apparently, it creates compatibility issues with certain modules, especially those related to Hermes or other specific configurations.
To resolve this, I had to disable the new architecture on iOS by using the following command:
RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=0 pod install

After running this command, everything worked perfectly again. If anyone else is having the same issue, give this a try! It really solved the problem for me.

After much debugging, uncertainty, and many hours of suffering, it came down to uninstalling and reinstalling dependency. There was no specific error message or change in git history that I could identify as the source of this. I literally ended up painfully removing code from the App till I discovered the issue with the library.

Have you downgraded the dependency? If so, which version?
